# Is it possible to use Autofac somehow within Unity3d?

Tags: unity-game-engine, autofac

I am using Unity3d 2018.1.0f3 which is using .net 4.6x and has netstandard 2.0. Does anyone know if its possible to get Autofac working within Unity? Currently, I get an error saying that it unloaded the assemblies due to possible runtime issues.

Thanks,
MH

Comment: I love Autofac, but for Unity you might want to look at https://github.com/modesttree/Zenject since it was built for Unity. At the very least, the readme should give you some ideas about how/where to bootstrap your app with Autofac once you get it imported.

Comment: Hey there, I definitely appreciate it. The two main reasons I wanted to use autofac was that there is an awesome tutorial series by CRJ Gaming as seen below and he specifically was using Autofac, but it was for a standalone server part of Unity that I am trying to make work within Unity instead.

That and I also bought a IoC course on Udemy that I wanted to take that was for Autofac as well. I am not sure exactly if it would carry over.

https://www.youtube.com/user/cjrgaming

Comment: It sounds like you might be new to Autofac and dependency injection. The project I linked has links to another series of [articles](http://www.sebaslab.com/ioc-container-unity-part-1/) that covers a lot of background and theory. It's well-worth studying.

Comment: I do appreciate it, and I probably will, unfortunately though, that doesn't help much with my issue at hand of trying to see if Autofac is able to work.

Comment: If you understand what dependency injection is, and how it can be implemented in Unity, you will be better equipped to figure out how to translate your tutorial into whatever you need to do in Unity. The DI library (Autofac) is nothing more than a tool to "wire up" dependencies and switching from one tool to another is trivial. Getting a DI tool to work in Unity is non-trivial, Autofac doesn't have the necessary bootstrap hooks built in to work with Unity. It doesn't help that there is another DI package called "Unity" that has nothing to do with Unity 3d.

Comment: You are very correct on that last part. Every time I try to search for Unity and Autofac on either google or github, I think I find something promising and then turns out it is the wrong Unity. : / The whole thing is less important now that I got what I was wanting to work, to work without Autofac to begin with, but I would still like to learn more about it, so looking into the Zenject will be my next thing to do. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea about the other stuff, and I use an older version of it, but I use AutoFac (3.5.2) with Unity with no issues at all. I think it needs slightly different setup for unity but not really sure. but I have an editor window system that uses ScriptableObjects for databases and seperate pages for different item types, and use autofac to inject the databases, and find all the sub pages and auto load them.

this is how I do it if this helps:

```
private ISWeaponDatabase weaponDb;
private ISQualityDatabase qualityDb;
private ISArmorDatabase armorDb;
private int currentTab;
private ContainerBuilder builder;
private BasePage[] pages;

DatabaseConfig dbConfig = Resources.Load<DatabaseConfig>("DatabaseConfig");
if (dbConfig == null) return;
if (weaponDb == null) weaponDb = ISWeaponDatabase.GetDatase<ISWeaponDatabase>(dbConfig.DataFolder, dbConfig.WeaponDatabase.DatabaseFile);
if (qualityDb == null) qualityDb = ISWeaponDatabase.GetDatase<ISQualityDatabase>(dbConfig.DataFolder, dbConfig.QualityDatabase.DatabaseFile);
if (armorDb == null) armorDb = ISArmorDatabase.GetDatase<ISArmorDatabase>(dbConfig.DataFolder, dbConfig.ArmorDatabase.DatabaseFile);
builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterInstance(weaponDb).As<ISWeaponDatabase>();
builder.RegisterInstance(armorDb).As<ISArmorDatabase>();
builder.RegisterInstance(qualityDb).As<ISQualityDatabase>();
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.GetAssembly(GetType())).Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("EditorPage")).As<BasePage>().SingleInstance();
IContainer container = builder.Build();
pages = container.Resolve<IEnumerable<BasePage>>().ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, would be nice to know what you tried until now, but basically, you'll import it as you'd import every other 3rd party library.

I assume you are on an up-to-date Windows Machine and you are using VS because you didn't give us any information on that.

1. Fire up your NuGet PM in VS (Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Console)
2. Command: Install-Package Autofac -Version 4.8.1
   Or your preferred way to get a NuGet package https://www.nuget.org/packages/Autofac/ (VS is of course also working)
3. Now you should have a package in /Packages/Autofac.4.8.1/lib/net45
4. Copy the DLL over to your assets/lib folder (or wherever you want to have it)
5. If you go back to Unity it will load Autofac now

Now you can go to any class you have and type "using Autofac" and get started.

Comment: I appreciate the reply. I have tried what you have mentioned. The framework I am trying to use came with Autofac 4.6.1, Autofac Configuration 4.0.1, Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration, and the associated other needed packages, I loaded them into Unity as you mentioned. I have tried different versions and what not, but it always gives an error within Unity that says it is "Unloading broken assemblies which may cause error at runtime" or something to that effect. I typically use Rider, but I also have tried in VS, everything has been tried with the most up to date versions as well.

Comment: @MostHated Did you put your unity into .NET4.x mode? Also in the 2018.x you still have to do that. File -> Build Settings -> Player Settings ... -> (opens up a window on the right side / in the inspector) find Scripting Runtime Environment. Its default value is 3.x, set it to 4.x and save it. A restart is required.

Comment: Yes, I am using 4.6x. I had mentioned that in my original post. Unfortunately, I have not seen many / any posts really in regards to this either. Neither people saying it works or doesn't work for them.

Comment: A fella in one of the other comments said that Autofac lacks the proper bootstrapping to work with Unity it looks like. Which is ok I guess. I got what I was wanting to work without Autofac, and then he linked me to a DI that is made to work with Unity, so I will have to check it out.